# Projecting multiple textures on surfaces relative to perspective in three.js

Tags: three.js, projection

Been working on a project where I unpack and display a game map on the web through three.js. It all looks good, except when a surface is marked as a SKY. As a placeholder I turned the texture into an `envMap`, but a surface can be marked as something else which I'd like to use the `envMap` for and wouldn't want to confuse the two. What I want to do is have these "sky-marked textures" be absolutely static, always facing the screen, no matter your perspective. Here's an example of what I'm looking for. https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPIiy.jpg

It would be like there was a hole in the surface looking straight through to a webpage's tiled background picture. I have experimented with RenderTargets in combination with various `envMap`s, but it has most often looked like a cubed map and the texture sliding and zooming in undesirable ways. I have attempted to use `glsl` but I could not have one instance for each texture, nor figure out how to feed the one instance with multiple textures.

So I ask what would be the best solution to achieve this effect?

Comment: Material with THREE.BackSide + texture atlas + screen space coords (in glsl). Geometry with indices for tiles in texture atlas.

Comment: @prisoner849 Those keywords got me very few results of what I'm looking for, let alone how to combine them. The "texture atlas" eludes me. How would be the best approach to combine an unknown number of textures of various sizes and then set the correct texture to the correct "geo index"?